# SSRS 2005 Second value of IIF(IsDBNull) not displaying

Tags: reporting-services

I'm pulling data from a DB that uses Address1 for street addresses and Address2 for PO Boxes.  In those cases where the street address does not exist, I need to display the PO Box.  The expression I've used for this claims to be syntactically correct, and where there is an Address1, I do indeed get the street address in my report.  Where Address1 is missing, I never see Address2.

Here is the expression:

```
=IIF(IsDBNull(First(Fields!Address1.Value, "ReportDataset")), First(Fields!Address2.Value, "ReportDataset"), First(Fields!Address1.Value, "ReportDataset"))
```

I could be dead wrong about this, but I've been working with the idea that perhaps the IsDBNull always evaluates to false because Address1 isn't actually NULL but rather an empty string. To that end, I've been trying to modify the evaluative portion of IsDBNull to accept something like or (Fields!Address1.Value, "ReportDataset") = "" but I can't seem to get the expression to be syntactically correct to even test that theory.

If there is something else wrong with my code, please let me know.

- Always learning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    =IIF(IsNothing(First(Fields!Address1.Value, "ReportDataset")) OR First(Fields!Address1.Value, "ReportDataset") = "", First(Fields!Address2.Value, "ReportDataset"), First(Fields!Address1.Value, "ReportDataset"))
```

Comment: Hmmmm, works beautifully.  I'll need to do some reading on the differences between IsDBNull and IsNothing.  As a newbie, I'm not familiar with the latter.  Well, for that matter, I'm barely familiar with the former!  ;-)  Thanks Chris!

Comment: IsDBNull is used to test for database null, whereas IsNothing tests for object null. Fields!Address1.Value is actually a string object, not a database field so IsNothing should be used. That may be why your expression was always false before - it was testing the wrtong condition.